# Using "any of" in a sentence

Tags: articles, subject-verb-agreement, singular-vs-plural

Which of the following is are correct or sound less jarring?

> 1) Do any of your friends have cars? 
>  2) Do any of your friends have a car?
>  3) Is any of your friends an actor?
>  4) Are any of your friends an actor?
>  5) Are any of your friends actors?

Comment: What do you think about them all?

Comment: 1 and 5 sound good to me.

Comment: My picks are 2 and 5, depending on what you are asking. Although I'm stumped as to why. It's just how I talk!

Answer (score 1):

In general match plural objects to plural subjects.

Between 1 & 2, choose 1. 
Number 2 asks (oddly) about the collective ownership among your friends of a single car.

Among 3, 4, and 5, choose #5. 
Number 3 is just odd. 
Number 4 mixes singular/plural, and again hints at some bizarre, collective acting career.

Comment: I don't think #2 is that odd. Let's say I need a ride to the airport. I arrange to get a ride with Joe, but that morning he calls me to tell me his car has a flat tire, and he won't be able to take me. I need a ride – and quick! I might ask him, _"Do any of your friends have a car?"_ (He may have several friends, but I only need a ride from one willing driver.)

Comment: I second that. If you are asking about the collective ownership among your friends of a single car, this is a natural way to ask. It seems like #1 is asking if any of my individual friends have (multiple) cars.